Quantlib- Error using PiecewiseConvexMonotoneZero() method
I am trying to replicate USD STD zero curve from Murex in QuantLib (Ver 1.35). Default setting for interpolation in Murex is Convex Monotone and USD SOFR is used for discounting cashflows for swaps on USD STD quoted in the market.
To start with I successfully constructed the interpolated USDSofr_curve using PiecewiseLinearZero() in QuantLib and used it as input to the SwapRateHelper() for USD STD. The error that I am getting is in the following piece of code written for USD STD:
Std_helpers += [
ql.SwapRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), tenor,joint_calendar,ql.Semiannual,
                  fixedConvention, fixedDayCount,Std_index,ql.QuoteHandle(),
                ql.Period(),ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(USDSofr_curve),settlementDays)
    
for rate, tenor in USDStd_swap_rates
]

USDStd_curve = ql.PiecewiseConvexMonotoneZero(0,joint_calendar,Std_helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())

with the error message:
1st iteration: failed at 13th alive instrument, pillar July 22nd, 2033, maturity July 22nd, 2033, reference date July 18th, 2024: root not bracketed: f[-1,1] -> [-4.015413e-03,-8.559693e+00]

I observed this error is occurring because of providing USDSofr_curve as input to the discounting curve in the SwapRateHelper(). If the input to the argument  discountingCurve=ql.YieldTermStructureHandle() in Swap RateHelper() is kept NULL, my code runs error free but the output discount rates are not matching with Murex on some pillar dates.
I am not able to explain how USDSofr_curve is causing this error and how to troubleshoot any further. Same error occurs when constructing EURIBOR 3M with ESTR as input for the discounting curve in SwapRateHelper().
I did come across a thread where this error was mentioned but no solution was discussed.
